# Failure during running rc.exe for Twisted on Windows 10

Tags: python, django

When I run `pip install channels` or `pip install twisted` Twisted fails with `Failed building wheel for twisted` Twisted is a required dependency for Django Channels. Here is the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1327: failure during running rc.exe
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1327
```

I tried various installs of Visual Studio and Build Tools, but could not make any progress. How do I get twisted to build on Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried a few options, including downloading the wheels version and pip failed the same way/same error as you have. The solution for me was copying both rc.exe and rcdll.dll from

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86

to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

Successfully installed now. Hope that helps.

Comment: This solution works for me, and I think this is because C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86 is not in system path variables.

Comment: A slightly better option than copying them (because Windows Updates may patch security issues in the original location in the future), is to use `mklink` from an Administrator elevated cmd prompt to link those two files.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you can download Twisted wheels from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

Choose Twisted version, Python version, and OS version.

Download the wheel and install from local file with:

`pip install path\to\Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Twisted should then install successfully.